# error while executing `VBoxManage` (vagrant/ virtualbox)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm following the installation tutorial from Data Science at the Command Line which includes the following steps:

```
$ mkdir MyDataScienceToolbox

$ cd MyDataScienceToolbox

$ vagrant init data-science-toolbox/data-science-at-the-command-line

$ vagrant up
```

This works perfectly on one of my computer but not the other. Why?

Both computers are using Virtualbox version:4.3.12 and Windows 7.

This is the error message:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'data-science-toolbox/data-science-at-the-command-line'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
```

for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

```
Command: ["import", "C:\\Users\\bernard\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\data-science-toolbox-VAGRANTSLASH-data-science-at-the-command-line\\0.0.5\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "packer-virtualbox-iso_1410075150030_92186", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "C:\\cygwin64\\home\\bernard\\VirtualBox VMs\\packer-virtualbox-iso_1410075150030_92186\\packer-virtualbox-iso-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting C:\Users\bernard\.vagrant.d\boxes\data-science-toolbox-VAGRANTSLASH-data-science-at-the-command-line\0.0.5\virtualbox\box.ovf...

OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the clone medium 'C:\cygwin64\home\bernard\VirtualBox VMs\packer-virtualbox-iso_1410075150030_92186\packer-virtualbox-iso-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'C:\cygwin64\home\bernard\VirtualBox VMs\packer-virtualbox-iso_1410075150030_92186/packer-virtualbox-iso-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like on the failing system your C: drive might not have enough free space. From the tail end of the error messages: "VERR_DISK_FULL".

Similar question on Super User: [What causes the "Failed to create the hard disk storage" error when creating a new virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/454039/what-causes-the-failed-to-create-the-hard-disk-storage-error-when-creating-a-n)

Comment: However, I keep running in another problem saying " VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system." I've looked around and some say, that it is because Hyper-V is installed which is not my case. Some say it is due to their CPU, but how do I know if that is the case? My CPU is specs are on http://ark.intel.com/products/33917/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9300-6M-Cache-2_50-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: It seems it indicate that I have VT-X enable so I don't understand the problem

Comment: Getting hardware virtualization turned on can be tricky and very different depending on your system. Check this [answer on SO](http://superuser.com/a/22917/113375) for a utility which may help.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue because my C drive is an SSD, and is nearly full (9 gb left)... My vagrant box is on my D: drive, how could I store everything related to vagrant on my D drive ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `sudo` , I got rid of errors when executing with root access.

Example:

```
sudo vagrant up
```